# XML vs. SQLite Database in Map Application

Tags: android, xml, database, google-maps, dictionary

I'm currently creating a campus map application that includes the information of every college of the university like Mission and Vision, List of Departments and Faculties, Pictures, etc. Is it okay to just use the XML as the database? The application is 14.5 MB memory.

Comment: I already answered here. Hope it helps and you can act accordingly: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21646135/1739882

Comment: @shree202 Is there an easy way to convert my XML files to this SQLiteDatabase since I'm still a beginner on Android Map Applications.

Comment: Probably, this should help you: http://martin.cubeactive.com/android-filling-a-table-from-resource-file-using-xml-sqlite/